# GCM Server Dependency

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

In pom.xml file i have added dependency for version 1.0.2 :

`<dependency> <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId> <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId> </dependency>`

but got this error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pn-ws: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.linkscreens.pinmedia:pn-ws:jar:0.7.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:jar:1.0.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:pom:1.0.2 (absent): Could not transfer artifact com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:pom:1.0.2 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, default,

I have tried to add these Repositories also but it did not work:
`
gcm-server-repository
https://raw.github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/master/releases

```
    <repository>
        <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
        <url>https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/raw/master/releases/</url>
    </repository>`
```

can anybody help me to figure this out?